# Variable inside readline.createInterface({}).on({}) is not updating

Tags: node.js

Trying to construct a request body with values from a `.csv` file, but my points array is not getting updated. I've done `console.log()` for the points array inside and at the end of the `on()` function, and the values are there as expected. But I console.log outside of the `on()` and it says the array is empty.

I know this is a scope issue, but not familiar with Node.js so much, so can't figure it out. Thanks.

```
// Detect anomalies in your spreadsheet
var points = []
var dict = {}
// Read the .csv file, convert date to Date object and number to float.
readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(CSV_FILE),
    terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
    var row = line.split(",")
    dict[new Date(row[0])] = parseFloat(row[1])
    points.push(dict)
});

// Create request body for API call
let body = { series: points, granularity: 'hourly' }
// Make the call
anomalyDetectorClient.entireDetect(body)
    .then((response) => {
        for (item in response.isAnomaly) {
            if (item) {
                console.log("An anomaly was detected from the series.")
                console.log("Value: " + response.expectedValues[response.indexOf(item)])
            } 
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

UPDATE:

I'm trying to move the async function into the `on()`, so the `points[]` has values in it...but there is a bad body in the request, my points array is taking an accumulative dictionary instead of a new dictionary each time it pushes. So that needs to be fixed first, before I can look again at the un-updated `points[]` outside of the last on().

Current code, I moved the API call into the last `on()` function (previously it was outside of it, with an `await` before it):

```
async function main() {
    let CSV_FILE = './request-data.csv'

    // Detect anomalies in your spreadsheet
    var points = []

    // Read the .csv file
    await readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(CSV_FILE),
        terminal: false
    }).on('line', function(line) {
        var row = line.split(",")
        // Convert date to Date object and number to float.
        var date = new Date(row[0])
        var dict = {}
        dict[date] = parseFloat(row[1])
        points.push(dict)
        console.log(points)
    }).on('close', function() {
         // Create request body for API call
        let body = { series: points, granularity: 'hourly' }

        console.log("Body series: " + body.series.timestamp + "Body granularity: " + body.granularity)
        // Make the call
        anomalyDetectorClient.entireDetect(body)
            .then((response) => {
                for (item in response.isAnomaly) {
                    if (item) {
                        console.log("An anomaly was detected from the series.")
                        console.log("Value: " + response.expectedValues[response.indexOf(item)])
                    } 
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })  
    })
```

UPDATE 2:

Using new code in the answer, there is a new error:
`Body series: undefinedBody granularity: hourly
{ Error: Time points should be uniformly spaced in time in hourly granularity with 1 gran as interval, ratio of missing points should be less than 10%, between 2018-03-01 00:00:00 and 2018-04-16 00:00:00 there should be at least 994 points, but got 47 points.` What does this means?

Confused because the body object looks good, it was printed with the error:

```
{ Error: Time points should be uniformly spaced in time in hourly granularity with 1 gran as interval, ratio of missing points should be less than 10%, between 2018-03-01 00:00:00 and 2018-04-16 00:00:00 there should be at least 994 points, but got 47 points.
    at new RestError (C:\Users\v-wiazur\Desktop\Anomaly Detector\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:1399:28)
    at C:\Users\v-wiazur\Desktop\Anomaly Detector\node_modules\@azure\ms-rest-js\dist\msRest.node.js:2494:37
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 'InvalidSeries',
  statusCode: 400,
  request:
   WebResource {
     streamResponseBody: false,
     url:
      'https://winonaanomalydetector.cognitiveservices.azure.com/anomalydetector/v1.0/timeseries/entire/detect',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     body:
      '{"series":[{"timestamp":"2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z","value":32858923},{"timestamp":"2018-03-02T00:00:00.000Z","value":29615278},{"timestamp":"2018-03-03T00:00:00.000Z","value":22839355},{"timestamp":"2018-03-04T00:00:00.000Z","value":25948736},{"timestamp":"2018-03-05T00:00:00.000Z","value":34139159},{"timestamp":"2018-03-06T00:00:00.000Z","value":33843985},{"timestamp":"2018-03-07T00:00:00.000Z","value":33637661},{"timestamp":"2018-03-08T00:00:00.000Z","value":32627350},{"timestamp":"2018-03-09T00:00:00.000Z","value":29881076},{"timestamp":"2018-03-10T00:00:00.000Z","value":22681575},{"timestamp":"2018-03-11T00:00:00.000Z","value":24629393},{"timestamp":"2018-03-12T00:00:00.000Z","value":34010679},{"timestamp":"2018-03-13T00:00:00.000Z","value":33893888},{"timestamp":"2018-03-14T00:00:00.000Z","value":33760076},{"timestamp":"2018-03-15T00:00:00.000Z","value":33093515},{"timestamp":"2018-03-16T00:00:00.000Z","value":29945555},{"timestamp":"2018-03-17T00:00:00.000Z","value":22676212},{"timestamp":"2018-03-18T00:00:00.000Z","value":25262514},{"timestamp":"2018-03-19T00:00:00.000Z","value":33631649},{"timestamp":"2018-03-20T00:00:00.000Z","value":34468310},{"timestamp":"2018-03-21T00:00:00.000Z","value":34212281},{"timestamp":"2018-03-22T00:00:00.000Z","value":38144434},{"timestamp":"2018-03-23T00:00:00.000Z","value":34662949},{"timestamp":"2018-03-24T00:00:00.000Z","value":24623684},{"timestamp":"2018-03-25T00:00:00.000Z","value":26530491},{"timestamp":"2018-03-26T00:00:00.000Z","value":35445003},{"timestamp":"2018-03-27T00:00:00.000Z","value":34250789},{"timestamp":"2018-03-28T00:00:00.000Z","value":33423012},{"timestamp":"2018-03-29T00:00:00.000Z","value":30744783},{"timestamp":"2018-03-30T00:00:00.000Z","value":25825128},{"timestamp":"2018-03-31T00:00:00.000Z","value":21244209},{"timestamp":"2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z","value":22576956},{"timestamp":"2018-04-02T00:00:00.000Z","value":31957221},{"timestamp":"2018-04-03T00:00:00.000Z","value":33841228},{"timestamp":"2018-04-04T00:00:00.000Z","value":33554483},{"timestamp":"2018-04-05T00:00:00.000Z","value":32383350},{"timestamp":"2018-04-06T00:00:00.000Z","value":29494850},{"timestamp":"2018-04-07T00:00:00.000Z","value":22815534},{"timestamp":"2018-04-08T00:00:00.000Z","value":25557267},{"timestamp":"2018-04-09T00:00:00.000Z","value":34858252},{"timestamp":"2018-04-10T00:00:00.000Z","value":34750597},{"timestamp":"2018-04-11T00:00:00.000Z","value":34717956},{"timestamp":"2018-04-12T00:00:00.000Z","value":34132534},{"timestamp":"2018-04-13T00:00:00.000Z","value":30762236},{"timestamp":"2018-04-14T00:00:00.000Z","value":22504059},{"timestamp":"2018-04-15T00:00:00.000Z","value":26149060},{"timestamp":"2018-04-16T00:00:00.000Z","value":35250105}],"granularity":"hourly"}',
     query: undefined,
     formData: undefined,
     withCredentials: false,
     abortSignal: undefined,
     timeout: 0,
     onUploadProgress: undefined,
     onDownloadProgress: undefined,
     proxySettings: undefined,
     operationSpec:
      { httpMethod: 'POST',
        path: 'timeseries/entire/detect',
        urlParameters: [Array],
        requestBody: [Object],
        responses: [Object],
        serializer: [Serializer] } },
  response:
   { body:
      '{"code":"InvalidSeries","message":"Time points should be uniformly spaced in time in hourly granularity with 1 gran as interval, ratio of missing points should be less than 10%, between 2018-03-01 00:00:00 and 2018-04-16 00:00:00 there should be at least 994 points, but got 47 points."}\n',
     headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
     status: 400 },
  body:
   { code: 'InvalidSeries',
     message:
      'Time points should be uniformly spaced in time in hourly granularity with 1 gran as interval, ratio of missing points should be less than 10%, between 2018-03-01 00:00:00 and 2018-04-16 00:00:00 there should be at least 994 points, but got 47 points.' } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is getting updated.  If you do `console.log(points)` inside your `line` event handler, you will see it accumulate date each time.

The issue is that you are looking at the array in the wrong place, before it has been populated.  The readline interface is asynchronous.  So, you call `readline.createInterface()` and set your event handler for the `line` event and then your code just keeps on running.  You are immediately calling `anomalyDetectorClient.entireDetect()` before the readline operation has done it's job.

The solution is to wait until the readline interface is done reading the whole file and until your `points` array is fully populated before you try to use the `points` array.

Here's one way to do that, where you process the `points` array in the `close` event handler for the readline interface:

```
// Detect anomalies in your spreadsheet
var points = [];
var dict = {};
// Read the .csv file, convert date to Date object and number to float.
readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(CSV_FILE),
    terminal: false
}).on('line', function(line) {
    var row = line.split(",");
    let point = {
        timestamp: new Date(row[0]), 
        value: parseFloat(row[1])
    };
    dict[point.date] = point.value;
    points.push(point);
    console.log(points);
}).on('close', function() {
    // now we're done reading the file
    console.log(points);   // all the points are here

    // now process the points
    // Create request body for API call
    let body = { series: points, granularity: 'hourly' };
    // Make the call
    anomalyDetectorClient.entireDetect(body).then((response) => {
        for (let item in response.isAnomaly) {
            if (item) {
                console.log("An anomaly was detected from the series.")
                console.log("Value: " + response.expectedValues[response.indexOf(item)])
            }
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });

}).on('error', function(err) {
    // handle errors here
    console.log(err);    
});
```

FYI, are you really sure you should be using `item in response.isAnomaly`?  `in` is NOT for arrays, it's for properties of objects.  It sorta, kinda works for arrays, but it can also not work lots of times.  `for/of` is built specifically for arrays as in `for (let item of response.isAnomaly) {...}`.  Also, for an array, `in` gets you the index of the value, not the array value.  `of` gets you the array value which is usually what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, that sounds correct! I often don't consider that file IO has asynchronization, but that makes tons of sense. I'll wait for your code, thanks!

Comment: @Azurespot - Code added.

Comment: Ah thanks, it's still coming back empty though. The `console.log()` has to be outside of the last `on()`. Putting one there, it comes back empty. And I can't put the API code inside the last `on()` because then it won't let me use `await`, which I definitely have to use it there, otherwise the body's `series: points` comes back as null. Unless I have my API call constructed wrong, or there is a bug in it.

Comment: @Azurespot - It does not sound like you're running the code I've shown you.  Now you're talking about `await` and there's no `await` in my code or in the code you have in your question.  So, sorry, but I can't answer questions about new code I can't see that you wrote that isn't in the question or in my answer.  I have no idea what that is.

Comment: @Azurespot - It's also possible, you have a coding error in your `line` event handler.  I'd suggest you add `console.log(points)` to the end of the `line` event handler and see if you can see it adding things to the `points` array.

Comment: what do you think of this line: `dict[new Date(row[0])] = parseFloat(row[1])` and this one `points.push(dict)`? I printed the `points` array right after and it was pushing the whole dictionary every single line. but then I changed the global `var dict` to local, so that it creates a new one each time, but still getting every single addition to the points array with the past dictionaries. So instead of getting one dictionary line for each line in the 47 lines in the file, it's pushing the accumulated dictionary to the points array.

Comment: @Azurespot - Yeah, `points.push(dict)` is clearly wrong.  You are pushing the same `dict` object into every array element which is not useful.  I don't know what you want in the `points` array.  You'd have to explain what you expect in that array?

Comment: sorry about that! I have been taking the async away and back in several times as I try it in my `on()` function. I will update my code with my current version. I did find an error in the points array, so even if I could move the API call into the last `on()`, it won't work with a bad body. I will update my code in second. Thanks!

Comment: @Azurespot - DO NOT REMOVE the code your question started with.  That would change the whole meaning of the question, rendering answers out-of-date.  Don't do that on stack overflow - ever.  If you want, you can ADD new versions of code to the end of your question (with notes in the question that these are an edit after-the-fact).

Comment: @Azurespot - Not knowing what you want your `points` array to be, I changed my code to make it something useful.  You can modify it as you see fit.

Comment: No, was not planning to remove it, just to add a new block and call it UPDATE. But thanks for the guidance. Cool, I will look at the points array now!

Comment: @Azurespot - You apparently tried to edit my code to remove the changes I made to make the `points` array meaningful.  Not sure why you tried to do that.  I rejected the edit.  I can help you fix the `points` array, but only if you describe what is supposed to be in it - what the exact format of the data is supposed to be.  Your question and comments don't tell us what it is supposed to be.

Comment: No I didn't, lol, so sorry you got that impression, I was trying to update my own question but added it to your answer instead. Argh, I am very tired I guess. But now I am debugging each of the lines and the points array looks just fine! When I print, it of course will print the points array up to that point, so the push() is not pushing more than it should. 
So then back to the original question.  Putting the API call into on() means I have to remove the async keyword. I did that, and ran it and it's saying `Error: body.series.timestamp cannot be null or undefined.`

Comment: The series property expects a Point[], I was hoping a object of points would do the trick, but I might have that wrong. Here is the API. It's confusing combined with my weak Node.js skills. Sorry this is turning into a mess. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cognitiveservices-anomalydetector/request?view=azure-node-latest#series

Comment: @Azurespot - Well, it looks like my code for the points array was really close.  The [Point interface doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/cognitiveservices-anomalydetector/point?view=azure-node-latest) shows an object with two properties, `timestamp: Date` and `value: Number`.  I've modified my code to make it into that.  The other requirement for `.entireDetect()` is that the array is sorted by timestamp.  If your original file isn't sorted that way, you may need to sort the array before calling `.entireDetect()`.

Comment: @Azurespot - FYI, I've never seen this interface, I'm just reading the doc.  You can too.

Comment: @Azurespot - The `Error: body.series.timestamp cannot be null or undefined.` is because your `points` array was wrong - there was no `.timestamp` property.  See my previous couple comments on that topic.

Comment: @Azurespot - FYI, I think we're long past the original question of the `points` array not updating.  If you continue to have issues with the `anomalyDetectorClient.entireDetect` interface that thorough study of the documentation can't figure out, then you may need to ask a new question, not just continue here.  I think we've long since answered the original question asked here.

Comment: I think that technically worked, the body printed in the new error and it looks how it should. But still coming up as a null for `series` property. But I think this is because of the spreadsheet values, so I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you so much for your help. It's weird, because that exact spreadsheet worked in similar sample code for both C# and Python. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, well the way we did it was a work around for the missing points[] values, which did work. So it did solve that problem. But yeah, now the problem is something else, so I thought we should stop here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Azurespot - Glad to get you through that and on to the next issue.

Comment: You helped me so much, can't thank you enough!! Also, I changed the granularity to 'daily' and the code worked! You saved me after hours of blood, sweat and tears. :)